# Docker container mounted file share path not updating

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

My docker compose file consists of services and volumes. Volumes are mapped to file shares. It was working all fine for few months but now I have changed my file share path but the service in container is still taking the old file share path.

My `docker volume inspect <container_id>` is showing new file share path. Even inside of container it is showing new file share path. I don't know from where, it is taking old file share path. I have deleted and recreated volumes and containers multiple times but no luck. Restarted docker service also, but no luck. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Updating mounted path to a different name worked for me finally.